# Android - Parse Query .include("key") Not Returning Full ParseObject Details

Tags: android, parse-platform, kotlin

So Im working on an app that uses parse v1.16.6 .
I wanted to include the relation "students" in the query from Class.

Here is what my query looks like:

```
val query: ParseQuery<ParseObject> = ParseQuery.getQuery("Class")
        query.include("students")
        query.findInBackground(object : FindCallback<ParseObject> {
            override fun done(objects: MutableList<ParseObject>?, e: 
            ParseException?) {
                if (e == null) {

                } else {
                    Log.wtf("Error", e.localizedMessage)
                }
            }
        })
}
```

This is taken from the interceptor and the "students" relation only returns this. Other fields in the students are not included.

```
"students":{
"__type":"Relation",
"className":"Student"
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't include users from a relation like that.  See this issue on GitHub: https://github.com/parse-community/parse-server/issues/4138

The suggestion is to use `object.get("relationKey").query().get()` (that's JS, will need to adapt by platform) on each individual object, or to use pointers if you need the include functionality.

Edit: Example of what I discussed in comments below

```
val query: ParseQuery<ParseObject> = ParseQuery.getQuery("Class")
        query.findInBackground(object : FindCallback<ParseObject> {
            override fun done(objects: MutableList<ParseObject>?, e: 
            ParseException?) {
                if (e == null) {
                    val relationQuery: ParseQuery<ParseObject> = ParseQuery.getQuery("Relation")
                    relationQuery.whereMatchesKeyInQuery("classId", "classId", query);
                    relationQuery.findInBackground(....)
                } else {
                    Log.wtf("Error", e.localizedMessage)
                }
            }
        })
}
```

Comment: So I would do another query to get the field in the relation? Even though I only need one field in the relation?

Comment: Relations are not able to be returned with query.include, regardless of how many fields you need from it. Looks like it, unfortunately.

Comment: they have this code sample in getting the parseobject relation

http://docs.parseplatform.org/android/guide/#relational-queries

Its quite the same as I did and it was not working. So looks like nesting the query will be the solution?

Comment: "Relational Query" is different than "Query including a Relation object". Relation objects work a bit differently than standard Parse objects, so the rules don't apply exactly the same. You could use the relational query, depending no your use, if there is a common id between a class and its Relation, and you just need the students from a single Class object. Or multiple of the students relations, using a query for classes, and then the query you actually run is on the Relation class using `matchesKeyInQuery` to match the classId.  But you can only get the relation or a class at a time.

Comment: Instead of a single query to get all class objects, then an individual query for each class object (1 + n queries), you could do this in 2 queries by performing the Class query, then performing the matchesKeyInQuery Relation query when that returns. This may be your best bet. Still nested, but not iteratively querying, so it will have much better performance.

Comment: I've added an (incomplete) example.  You'll have to add the callbacks, as well as set up those classIds.

Comment: Thanks man. I think I'll just be nesting the query. I originally though that calling val students = object.getParseObject("students") during the done callback would let me access the relation object.